# Use of ampersand operator in Scanf

Tags: c

When using `scanf` for arrays, it seem that the function works fine whether I use '&' operator or not. I want to know how the compiler sees the '&'operator in case of arrays of character

I already know that `scanf` passes pointer when a single character is used.In case of arrays the variable itself is storing the pointer to first element.
My exact question is when I use `&ch`(while ch is string) do we create double pointer? And how does Compiler operates then

```
int main() 
{
    char ch,s[100],sen[100];
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    scanf("%s",s);
    scanf(" %[^\n]%*c",sen);

}
```

Comment: Note:: Array name decays to pointer.

Comment: *"I use &ch(while ch is string) do we create double pointer?"* - No. Applying `&` to a formal non-function variable *always* results in a pointer-to-type, where the type is of the underlying operand. Ex: `int a;` then `&a` is `int *`. Given `char s[N];`, then `&s` is `char (*)[N]`. That's a pointer to and char array of `N` magnitude. It should not be confused with a pointer to `N` chars. They sound the same, but its a "type" thing; they're different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

Comment: If you pass `char s[100]` as an argument to a function such as `input(char s[100])` you will discover that `scanf("%s", s)` implemented in the function works, but `scanf("%s", &s)` does not. Now they are very different, in the first case a pointer to the original array is passed to `scanf` but in the second case the address of the pointer *argument* is passed to `scanf`, or pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When using scanf for arrays, it seem that the function works fine whether I use '&' operator or not.

"Seems" being the operative word.

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T` will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

If you call `scanf` as

```
scanf( "%s", s );
```

the *expression* `s` is converted from type "100-element array of `char`" (`char [100]`) to "pointer to `char`" (`char *`) and its value is the address of the first element of the array (`&s[0]`).

If you call `scanf` as

```
scanf( “%s”, &s );
```

`s` is the operand of unary `&`, so the conversion doesn’t occur, and the *expression* `&s` has type "pointer to 100-element array of `char`" (`char (*)[100]`).  This is a problem, since the `%s` conversion specifier expects an argument of type `char *`.  Passing an argument of any other type results in *undefined behavior* - the operation may work as expected, or it may crash outright, or it may corrupt data, or it may leave the program in a bad state such that it crashes later, etc.

Both expressions `s` and `&s` resolve to the same *value* - the address of an array is the same as the address of its first element - but their *types* are different, and in C different pointer types may have different representations (IOW, the way the address value is stored for a `char *` may be different from the way an address value is stored for a `char (*)[100]`).  So

```
scanf( "%s", &s );
```

could fail on some platforms.

> My exact question is when I use &ch(while ch is string) do we create double pointer?

No. If `ch` is declared as `char ch`, then `&ch` has type `char *`.  If `ch` is declared as `char ch[N]`, then `&ch` has type `char (*)[N]`.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword in this case is `array decay`. The compiler automatic convert the array to an pointer to the first element of this array.

In your case you have to pass a pointer to `scanf`. In your first line you pass the address of `ch` via the `&` operator. You also can write `&Array[0]` to point to the first element of your array or you write `Array` and the compiler will automatic resolve it to `&Array[0]`.

```
int main()
{
    char Array[1];

    scanf("%c", Array);

    printf("%p\n\r", &Array[0]);
    printf("%p\n\r", Array);

    return 0;
}
```

Both arguments are the same address. So in case of `scanf` you use the `&` operator if you want to get a single integer or a single character from your keyboard:

```
int value;
scanf("%d", &value);
```

If you want to receive a char array you pass the array without the `&` operator and let the compiler do the work for you.

```
char Array[20];
scanf("%s", Array);
```